# LaTeX Headings Question

Tags: sectioning, books

I am in the process of finishing a book.  I hove noticed that for some reason the chapter headings and section headings are not all in the same font style.  Sometimes the style will be slanted Capital letters and then a heading will switch to upright Capitals.  I have never had this before.   It is very frustrating.  Does anybody have an idea as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be way easier for others to help you if you can provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that): that is a small, compilable document reproducing the problem. It can sometimes be hard to create, but it is often necessary, since most of the time it is really hard to guess what can be causing the problem without an actual code reproducing it.

Comment: Getting out my crystal ball, I suspect that you are seeing font substitutions because the formatting you've chosen for the headings needs a font face that the font doesn't provide. Check the log file for font substitution warnings.

Comment: without a key, we cannot start a bike like that we can't able to give a solution without MWE

Comment: I guess  what you call ‘headings’ are meant to be *headers*?